# New VSTS Git Private Repository

Tags: git, repository, azure-devops, private

TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://jointtech.visualstudio.com/

I created a new VSTS account and a new repository. When VSTS starts VS 2017 I get this error message. If I try to connect inside VS 2017 I get this error also. I try clearing the cached data in Appdata.

Have others seen this situation? I am trying to add code management to my team. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 0):

If the solutions listed in [How To Fix TF30063 Error - You Are Not Authorized To Access Team Foundation Service Error](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-fix-tf30063-error-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-team-foundation-serv/) are not enough, do check if you can browse that project if the VSTS web interface.

If not, contact your admin in order to be added as a user allowed to accessed that project.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the account that you are logged into Visual Studio is different to the one used to create the account.

Open Visual Studio and on the Team Explorer tab click "Connect".

If you have permission you can select your account from the list. If you don't see your account you can add the credentials and select it.

Note: even if you use the same email address, you could have both a personal (MSA) and a corporate (AzureAD) identity linked to it. I recommend changing your MSA to a different alias that does not conflict with an AzureAD email.

Answer (score 0):

​I had this problem and I ran Visual Studio as Administrator and it has been solved.